# Anyone have an idea how to dismiss this DatePicker/Subview

Tags: ios

This is the method I use to display a UIPickerView when a button is pressed, what method would I used to dismiss it?

```
if (buttonIndex == 4) {
    int height = 255;
```

//create new view

```
UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, height)];
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
```

//add toolbar

```
UIToolbar * toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

//add button

```
UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:@selector(dismissCustom:)];
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButtonItem, nil];
```

//add date picker

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime ;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 250);
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:nil/*@selector(changeDateInLabel:)*/ forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [newView addSubview:datePicker];
```

//add popup view

```
[newView addSubview:toolbar];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

//animate it onto the screen

```
CGRect temp = newView.frame;
    temp.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds);
    newView.frame = temp;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    temp.origin.y -= height;
    newView.frame = temp;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the view, do another animation. Just reverse the frame setting so it moves off of the screen. When the animation completes, remove the 'newView' by calling `[newView removeFromSuperview]`.

You should consider using the newer block form of UIView animations. It will make it much easier.

One other thing. If you have a custom view class, why doesn't that custom class do all the work to set itself up?

Also, it is standard convention for class names to begin with an upper case letter. This makes it easy to tell a classname from a variable name when looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks for that, i will give that a go! Just a question, what is the newer block form? And i will keep that last bit in mind.

Comment: Oh and also I didn't have the custom view class setting it all because I was just testing something. I accidentally put the wrong code in.

Comment: Look at the UIView reference docs. Look at the list of methods under **Animating Views with Blocks**